# Get mouse buttons state being in background

Tags: winapi

I need something like `GetKeyboardState()` but for mouse. I do not need to handle an event when the mouse button pressed, just need to know if the buttons are up or down at some moment. This is for toy animation program.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using C/C++, but does it matter for WinAPI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0)
{
    // left button is down
}
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON) < 0)
{
    // right button is down
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how about the middle one?

Comment: Maybe `VK_MBUTTON`? :)